# "Cannot find source file": Debug where cmake looked for it

Tags: debugging, cmake

When designing my CMakeLists, I often run into this kind of error:

```
Cannot find source file:

  foo.hpp

Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm .hpp
.hxx .in .txx
```

To debug thoses issues, I would really like to know where CMake looked for this file!

I can find some SO questions about this, but they are always specific to a given project, not a general purpose debug solution.

Comment: It's always so specific because you literally have to specify where CMake should look for your source files.

Comment: yes but there must be sth like "print the list of directories where at this point you looked for files" so that I can see which one is missing..

Answer (score 0):

When you pass `file.hpp` to `add_executable()` or `add_library()` command, CMake searches the file:

- under current source directory (*CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR*),
- under current binary directory (*CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR*).

Also, CMake is able to detect, if given file is generated by means of `add_custom_command()` command in the current `CMakeLists.txt` file (that is, the file doesn't exist yet, but it will be created at *build* stage in a way known by CMake).

Comment: This error message can also occur when calling `target_link_libraries` for instance, in which case I suppose it looks for it in some dirs specified by the library, etc. How can I be sure I get the complete liste of dirs? Isn't there some debug flag to cmake to get that?

Comment: If I correctly remember, type of the message you quoted doesn't occur with `target_link_libraries`. With that call you may get `cannot find -l..` message, which is generated by the linker at the **build stage**.

Comment: Last time I ran into this error, it was because I was linking an interface library whose target_source was defined with a relative path instead of absolute. "foo.cpp" was not even present in my add_executable command, only in the call to target_source within the library's CMakeLists.

Comment: `target_source` is just another way for specifying source file for the library. I am not sure, but I guess the same principles (as describe in the answer) are applied for that case.

Comment: A rough version of the upper mentioned problem: https://pastebin.com/raw/NFtufCcp But I don't want a solution specific to this weird problem, because I *always* have debugging issues of this kind with CMake, but they are all different. No debug trace or something? Good practices for cmakelists debugging?

Comment: Not sure which kind of problem you have with debugging such errors. CMake points you to the line which creates executable/library with non-existed source file. (CMake won't traverse to *INTERFACE* library, as it doesn't produce an output by itself). Then you should either fix path to the file, so the file would exists under current source or binary directory, or write a rule (`add_custom_command`) which creates the file. CMake doesn't check any "magic" directory for find the file: it should be located either under source or binary directory.